# Do AngularJS apps have a "stack?"

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating an AngularJS app.  This app has a "screen" where someone selects a series of options.  One of those options loads a Customer list.  And on that customer list, I have the option to create a customer:

```
[Main Menu] (/) 
    -> [Options Select] (/options)
    -> [Customer Picker] (/options/customer)
    -> [Customer Create] (/options/customer/add)
```

So basically `Customer Create` is just this "state?" that the app can be in.  If I were to navigate using the UI and then reload the page and start over from this page, it makes no different because the Angular application itself doesn't consider how I got to this page to be a "stack" of items.  There isn't some View Controller that I've popped something onto, there are just a bunch of independent routable destinations.

I'm used to thinking that I could just instantiate a customer picker controller and throw it on the stack and transition to it... but that doesn't work here, does it?

If, say, I wanted the customer app picker to be "smarter," then I'd have to figure out some way of letting the customer picker know what I expected out of it using some sort of options passed into it via the router OR create a slight variation based on each particular use case I want.

Comment: Controllers are ViewModels , so if you need the picker to stay opened if you come back to whatever page you opened it , migrate the picker logic and datas into a service which will persist the picker state(opened/closed). AngularJS apss dont have a stack unless you create one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

So, by default, Angular doesn't have much anything like this, but by using `$localtionProvider` or other libraries, there are a number of different ways that you can handle this.

- You can use `$locationProvider.path()` to provide a hashtag or HTML5 (real) path
- You can use `$locationProvider.search()` to pass an object in the URL to persist states
- You can use something like [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair) to save a more complex state on the client, using whatever methods are available to that client

If you also use `$routeProvider` and switch your controllers/views around with that, then you can use simple links between different views, might be a way for you to accomplish your desired tasks with somewhat simpler code.

Specifically to what you're looking to do (if I understand it correctly that is), you could use the `$locationProvider.search()` method to store your stack information. Something like this:

```
$scope.go = function (where) {
    var currentSearch = $location.search();
    currentSearch.viewStack.push(where);
    $location.search(currentSearch);
    $location.path(where);
}
```

An important caveat when using `$locationProvider.search()` though is that it won't store more than one level of object, meaning that the object you pass into that function should not contain anything other than simple types and arrays.

With this approach, you'd have to add something to your top level Controller that would interpret the `viewStack` array that you're putting into the search. A popular pattern here seems to be to have one controller at the root of the application that is long-lived, and then other transient ones underneath. You can use the top-level controller for its scope too, but that gets into a kinda murky 'global' scope that you probably want to avoid.

The great thing about angular is the amount that it allows you to limit the JS that you use. Anytime where you can use less custom written JS and rely more on angular's way of working things, the better off it seems to make you in the long run.

Comment: I guess part of my problem is that I've been using the jQuery Mobile adapter.  Some of angular's features are disabled when using it.  I have been okay with what has been missing for now, but the $routeProvider is missing quite a bit.  Perhaps I'll try getting rid of it and seeing how it works.

Comment: Also, I wanted to upvote your comment, but I don't feel that it particularly answered the question directly.  If you wanted to add a bit more information about how/why Angular doesn't work as a stack, I'd be more than happy to mark your answer as acceptable!